# Cannot change database from configure.php in osCommerce

Tags: oscommerce

​

I tried both includes/configure.php, and admin/includes/configure.php, neither contains data about the real database. these are the data in the admin/includes/configure.php:

```
defined('DB_SERVER_USERNAME') or define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME', 'root');
defined('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD') or define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD', '');
defined('DB_DATABASE') or define('DB_DATABASE', 'trueloaded');
```

and this is in the includes/configure.php:

```
defined('DB_SERVER') or define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
defined('DB_SERVER_USERNAME') or define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME', 'root');
defined('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD') or define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD', '12345678');
defined('DB_DATABASE') or define('DB_DATABASE', 'trueloadeduk');
```

nothing happens if I change the database here.

I am using the latest version of oscommerce 4.13
​